# Python exec() returns None

Tags: python

When executing a string with exec(), it returns None.

```
tree_1= '''def tree():
  input_user = input('elektriciteit | Y&N')
  if input_user == 'Y':
    return 1800000
  else:
    input_user = input('accelerator | Y&N')
    if input_user == 'Y':
      return 2170701
    else:
      return 2170705
tree()'''


output = exec(tree_1)
print(output)
```

How to save the return value to a variable. Eval is not working.

Comment: `exec`, when invoked this way will operate in the current context -- if you changed `tree()'''` to `result = tree()'''`, you could just `print(result)`.  I'm not a huge fan of this approach though.

Comment: Yes; that's what `exec` does. Why are you using `exec` in the first place?

Comment: "*Eval is not working*" - but you are not using `eval`, you are using `exec` (which *is* working).

Comment: Last week it worked, now I came to this part of the code en I got that 'None' return. Maybe python versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer.

```
tree_1= '''def tree():
  input_user = input('elektriciteit | Y&N')
  if input_user == 'Y':
    return 1800000
  else:
    input_user = input('accelerator | Y&N')
    if input_user == 'Y':
      return 2170701
    else:
      return 2170705
result = tree()'''

exec(tree_1)

global result
print(result)
```